# The song playing in Nana episode 22 when Takumi and Hachi meet on her apartment and Nana witness

Tags: music, nana

In *Nana* episode 22, at 20:35, there's a song playing when Takumi and Hachi meet on her apartment and Nana witness.

What is that song? I think it's an unreleased one.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think it was just a piece of unnamed music that was used to transition the scene to the end credits and the song Starless Night. I've checked the music through the episodes, and none of them really sounded like that small portion.